# `to_datetime` and `parse_dates` both failing to convert dtype to datetime[ns]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm loading some data which has a `Date` column. Here is a sample for reproduction:

```
    Date        Time        Latitude    Longitude
0   01/02/1965  13:44:18    19.246      145.616
1   01/04/1965  11:29:49    1.863       127.352
2   01/05/1965  18:05:58    -20.579     -173.972
3   01/08/1965  18:49:43    -59.076.    -23.557
4   01/09/1965  13:32:50    11.938      126.427
```

loading this data with with `parse_dates=['Date']` results in a different presentation of the `Date` column, but leaves the type as `Object`:

```
    Date                Time        Latitude    Longitude
0   1965-01-02 00:00:00 13:44:18    19.246      145.616
1   1965-01-04 00:00:00 11:29:49    1.863       127.352
2   1965-01-05 00:00:00 18:05:58    -20.579     -173.972
3   1965-01-08 00:00:00 18:49:43    -59.076     -23.557
4   1965-01-09 00:00:00 13:32:50    11.938      126.427
```

`df.info()` shows dtype of `Object` instead of `datetime[ns]`:

```
Data columns (total 21 columns):
 #   Column                      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                      --------------  -----  
 0   Date                        23412 non-null  object
```

The same thing happens if I use `pd.to_datetime()` AFTER loading the data.

The problem is that I cannot use the `.dt` attribute on a column/series of type `Object`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data/database.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
data.Date = data.Date.apply(pd.to_datetime) 

data[data.Date.dt.year >= 1970]

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike value
```

Where this operation would normally work fine if the `Date` column was the correct type. Any clues appreciated.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` should work. there is also an `errors=` argument that you can play with. Are you sure that all of your records are valid dates?

Comment: @MattR No, I am looking through them now. I also noticed that accessing a single index of the `Date` column results in a `timestamp` object. I don't know if that's a clue or not.

Comment: Check if the dates has different time zones. Use `utc=True` option if it’s the case.

Comment: @QuangHoang There is no timezone in the data, but setting `utc=True` did fix the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `errors` parameter in `to_datetime()` method and set that equal to 'coerce' so basically if any of your date value is not in format of date or `to_datetime()` method doesn't able to parse them then it set those values to `NaT` and continue further parsing:-

```
data['Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date'],errors='coerce')
```

Now check the dtype of columns by:-

```
data.dtypes

It will gives you:-
Date         datetime64[ns]
Time                 object
Latitude             object
Longitude           float64
```

Now as you see your Date column is changed to **'datetime'** now you can make use of `dt` class

finally:-

```
data[data['Date'].dt.year >= 1970]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a whirl. Can you expound on some of the details of what's going wrong here that requires the extra use of the `errors` argument?

Comment: Great, thank you. I found 3 out of the 23 thousand rows had a format like this `1975-02-23T02:58:41.000Z`, which must have been throwing a wrench in the works. Also, @QuangHoang suggestion of `utc=True` worked to fix the error.

Comment: Even after `errors='coerce'` it can leave you will `object` instead of `datetime64[ns]`...